# Hover event in toastr angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use this library : https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr . I want some event like ajax when I hover in toastr . I tried something like :

```
$('#toastr-container).on('mouseenter',function(){
 //do something
})
toastr.info.on('mouseenter',function(){
 //do something
})
```

but no work . How can I do this . Please help me

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Do you get any errors? Your code in the snippet seems to be missing a `'`.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen it my bad when copy in here . It's just not work . No error